# How to map left shift to right shift?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

My left shift fails to work on *some* keys (e.g. `nzbkd8.;`) *sometimes*, while right shift always works on all keys. Reinstalled all keyboard drivers (Uninstall -> Reboot), issue persists. Trying an AHK workaround by remapping each individual key that fails via LShift, to RShift - but that's not working:

```
<+n::>+n        # LShift + n --> RShift + n
LShift::RShift  # testing only one at a time
```

The script reloads successfully, but is ineffective. Since LShift *always* works one *some* keys, I ruled out it being a broken key issue - i.e. the OS should always receive the LShift signal, so AHK should be able to capture it and remap to RShift, but this doesn't happen. Any resolution?

---

**Additional info**:

- **System**: Win-10 Home, ASUS ROG Strix [GL702VSK](https://amzn.to/2TAedUh)
- **AHK version**: 1.1.29.01
- **Drivers**: *HID Keyboard Device* (x2), *PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 Keyboard (101/102-Key)*

Comment: Your script maps left shift to right shift, but from the problem description I think you want to do just the opposite.

Comment: @harrymc Isn't the input to the left of `::` and output to the right? Tried your suggestion regardless, didn't work - `>+n::<+n` in particular did nothing for LShift, but RShift outputs `<N`.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will map right-shift to left-shift:

```
RShift::LShift
```

You can see the keys that are being pressed or mapped by opening the
AutoHotkey window and using the menu *View > Key history and script info*
and using <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh.

The mapping of `<+n::>+n` is not required and the syntax is wrong.

Comment: I should've clarified `RShift::LShift` is what I tried first; also, strangely, `LShift` _never registers_ in the window unless followed-up by another key, whereas `RShift` does by itself. Also, in case my use intent isn't clear, it's a matter of _convenience_; `RShift` is much more awkward to press, and inhibits my typing speed, which is actually very problematic for my programming.

Comment: The above works fine for me, but perhaps it's something to do with some installed product on your computer. Check if the LShift problem arrives when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: Just did `Safe Mode -> Minimal`, still broke. Also, the behavior is strange: spamming `LShift + n` enough, eventually `N` is typed, and even several in a row. One instance, `LShift` refused to work at all - another, after 20 mins of no typing, if worked perfectly with all keys for a few minutes. The only installs I've done today are a few TensorFlow 2 reinstalls in separate virtual environments in Anaconda, and I doubt I have a virus, though I could run a full scan.

Comment: I noticed in the AHK Window, that if `LShift + n` doesn't `N`, then `LShift` isn't logged at all, only `n`. What's most unclear is how key registry is done "retroactively" - only deciding whether to register `LShift` or not based on subsequent keypresses.

Comment: You did Clean Boot, not Safe mode. If the problem is intermittent, this might be a hardware problem with the keyboard. In all cases, `RShift::LShift` should work and is what you asked for.

Comment: Did Shift + Restart -> Enable Safe Mode, got black desktop w/ "Safe Mode" written on each corner - didn't work. But no, R->L doesn't do it. Even given my descriptions on "retroactive" key registry, do you still suspect it a hardware problem? Seems like software to me

Comment: It works for me. How do you see that it doesn't?

Comment: As noted earlier, the goal is to _physically_ use LS; from what I understand (and observe), `RS->LS` implies physical usage via RS. When I F5 in AHK window, LS registers only in combination with certain other keys, not just itself - and those keys are ones that get capitalized ("retroactively"). With `RS->LS`, `RS` logs `RS + LS`, but `RS + key` logs `RS +  key`, and `LS + key` remains unchanged.

Comment: Also, I've been temporarily using `q::RShift`, but only now tested `q::LShift` - and both work flawlessly. Don't know how to interpret this - I surely assume keyboard keys aren't wired in series, which would be some toaster-era mistake.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `shell:startup` to create (or copy paste existing) script. This should make it so your scripts are being "Run as administrator".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arrai.png]

I think whatever issue you might be having is cause of that. I've had issues with that before. I tried to leave is as comment but I'm too weak a user. I do not have enough rep.

---

Here are some keys / links you might find helpful:

```
^ for CTRL
! for ALT
# for Windows Key
+ for Shift
Space ( ) %20 
Comma (,) %2C
Question Mark (?) %3F
Period (.) %2E
Exclamation Point (!) %21
Colon (:) %3A
Semicolon (;) %3B
```

- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
- https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#numpad
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430404/how-do-i-change-shortcut-keys-with-autohotkey
- https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/43779-reload-this-script-shortcut-solved/#entry409204

Comment: Already had it in startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a .reg file that will remap LeftShift to send the RightSHift keycode.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,36,e0,2a,00,00,00,\
  00,00
```

All one-to-one key remaps can be caccomplished this way.
Here's my PowerShell(Admin!) script that allows me to add/remove mappings once scancodes are determined with a keyboard test utility:

```
##############################################################
$SimplePairs = @(
# 0x02, 0x4f # 1 ! > 1 end
# 0x03, 0x50 # 2 @ > 2 ↓
# 0x04, 0x51 # 3 # > 3 pg dn
# 0x05, 0x4b # 4 $ > 4 ←
# 0x06, 0x4c # 5 % > 5
# 0x07, 0x4d # 6 ^ > 6 →
# 0x08, 0x47 # 7 & > 7 home 
# 0x09, 0x48 # 8 * > 8 ↑
# 0x0a, 0x49 # 9 ( > 9 pg up
# 0x0b, 0x52 # 0 ) > 0 Ins
# 0x34, 0x53 # . > > . Del
# 0x00, 0x3a # Null > CapsLock
)
$ExtendedPairs = @(
 0x36, 0xe0, 0x2a, 0x00 # Right-Shift(0xe036) > Left-Shift(0x002a)
# 0x5d, 0xe0, 0x1d, 0xe0 # ContextMenu(0xe05d) > R Ctrl(0xe01d)
)
$ByteCount = 2 * $SimplePairs.Length + $ExtendedPairs.Length + 16
$Remap = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList $ByteCount
$Remap.Length
$Remap[8] = $SimplePairs.Length/2 + $ExtendedPairs.Length/4 + 1
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $SimplePairs.Length ; $i += 2) {
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 12] = $SimplePairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 14] = $SimplePairs[$i + 1]
}
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $ExtendedPairs.Length ; $i += 4) {
   $Offset = $SimplePairs.Length * 2
   $Remap[$i + 12 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i + 13 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 1]
   $Remap[$i + 14 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 2]
   $Remap[$i + 15 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 3]
}
$Splat = @{
Path  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
Name  = 'ScanCode Map'
Value = $Remap
Force = $True
}
$Splat['Value'] | format-hex
New-ItemProperty @Splat
```

Comment: What is this registry editor you use? [This](https://puu.sh/FdcxZ/5ae3974e4e.png) is what I see when I navigate to your shown folder in the default editor. Do I just make a .reg file and dump it straight in there?

Comment: I use the default registry editor. The `ScanCode Map` vallue doesn't exist by default, as normally none is needed. The first block I posted can be saved as a `.reg`` file & merged. A Restart isnecessary for the value to be read. The more elaborate code is a **PowerShell** script that can be easily modified to remap different keys and all the byte array magic is done by the code.

Comment: In PowerShell code `#`is the comment indicator. So in the code I posted, all  the remaps (ones I've created at other times) are commented out except RShift=>LShift. I left them in as examples for those who want to play with the code. The numeric set of remaps assigns the top-row number key codes to the numeric keypad keys --- so the numeric keypad is always numbers regardless of NumLock state!

Comment: Now my `LShift` died entirely, so @harrymc was likely correct on it being a hardware issue, so I can't even test this - thanks for the info regardless